# What's the proper connection string to MySQL db for ActiveRecord on TravisCI?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, travis-ci, rails-event-store

Here is one of my problematic builds:

- https://travis-ci.org/RailsEventStore/rails_event_store_active_record/jobs/268876871

Here is the error:

```
Mysql2::Error:
Access denied for user 'travis'@'%' 
to database 'rails_event_store_active_record'
```

and here is a list of connection strings that I tried

- `DATABASE_URL=mysql2://travis:@127.0.0.1/rails_event_store_active_record?pool=5`
- `DATABASE_URL=mysql2://travis@127.0.0.1/rails_event_store_active_record?pool=5`
- `DATABASE_URL=mysql2://travis@localhost/rails_event_store_active_record?pool=5`

This is how I create the DB:

```
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE rails_event_store_active_record;'
```

And the code responsible for connecting:

```
ENV['DATABASE_URL'] ||= "postgres://localhost/rails_event_store_active_record?pool=5"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.failure_color = :magenta
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
```

Everything works fine [when I test my gem with Postgresql](https://travis-ci.org/RailsEventStore/rails_event_store_active_record/jobs/268876870) but it fails for Mysql.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL - documents how to connect to MySQL DB and I am not sure what I am doing wrong right now.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried one more option and it worked. Apparently I had to use `root` user instead of `travis` despite what the documentation says...

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql2://root:@127.0.0.1/rails_event_store_active_record?pool=5
```